# SQL query attempting to check for duplicate name/email in user list (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL novice and could use some assistance trying to write a script to identify dupes in a database by first name, last name and email and a unique ID (first, last, ID are in one table and email ID are in another).
I was thinking it would be ideal to have both sets in a row and so I wrote this query, but it is super slow after I added the "lower" commands (40 million records in the DB).
Any suggestions on ways to improve?

```
select 
e1.ID RFID1, e1.email Email1, apf1.name_first First1, apf1.name_last Last1, --first account details
e2.ID2 RFID2,e2.email Email2, apf2.name_first First2, apf2.name_last Last2  --second account details

from account_email e1
inner join account_email e2 on lower(e1.email)=lower(e2.email)
inner join account apf1 on e1.ID=apf1.ID
inner join account apf2 on e2.ID=apf2.ID

where 
e1.ID != e2.ID --don't match against the same account
and lower(apf1.name_first)=lower(apf2.name_first) --same first
and lower(apf1.name_last) =lower(apf2.name_last)  --same last
```

This is a second attempt I made that was equally taxing:

```
select * 
from
(
select e1.ROI_ID RID1, e1.ROI_FAMILY_ID, LOWER(e1.email) email1, LOWER(apf1.name_first) first1, LOWER(apf1.name_last) last1
from account_email e1
inner join account_profile_family apf1 on e1.ROI_FAMILY_ID=apf1.ROI_FAMILY_ID
) team1,
(
select e2.ROI_ID RID2, e2.ROI_FAMILY_ID, LOWER(e2.email) email2, LOWER(apf2.name_first) first2, LOWER(apf2.name_last) last2
from account_email e2
inner join account_profile_family apf2 on e2.ROI_FAMILY_ID=apf2.ROI_FAMILY_ID
) team2
where
team1.RID1 != team2.RID2
and team1.email1=team2.email2
and team1.first1=team2.first2
and team1.last1 =team2.last2
```

Answer (score 0):

its because using functions on columns make it non-sargable and database engine can not use index on them or sometimes use the statistics,
the best solution would be to make an Indexed computed column for those emails, firstname and last name , they even don't need to be persisted.

Comment: Hey @eshirvana I hear what you are saying but I'm not sure how to put that into practice. Is that something that can be done via a SQL query or does it require database/table manipulation? This query is for a software as a service platform that I don't have access to the server/database, my only access is via a browser based SQL window - so if it can be done through SQL that would be great!

Comment: CREATE INDEX email_idx 
ON account_email  (email); but it would be good to check other indexes on the table and I could take some time to build the new index and impact performances

Comment: @GeoffGarcia in needs table structure manipulation